# Recommended approach for installing and using new kernels?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Possibly this isn't supported yet, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the documentation? I added Python3, R, and Julia kernels vi Docker-extended, but but I'm not sure how to expose them in your notebook environment.